# Error: Multiplicity constraint violated

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, code-first

I have a Class in code firs that relation with self .

```
 public class OrganizationalUnit
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual OrganizationalUnit ParentUnit { get; set; }}

    public  ICollection<OrganizationalUnit> OrganizationalSubUnits { get; set; }
```

When i want edit a item of OrganizationalUnit , i get error

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'OrganizationalUnit_Parent_Target' of the relationship 'AutomationDataEntryModel.OrganizationalUnit_Parent' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

in ViewModel

```
 OrganizationalUnit unit = db.OrganizationalUnit.Find(SelectedOrganizationalUnit.Id);
 unit.Name = Name;
 unit.TypeId =Type;
 unit.ParentId = ParentOrganizationalUnit;

 db.SaveChanges();
```

**Edit**

I use fluent API for it

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationalUnit>()
   .HasOptional(a => a.ParentOrganizationalUnit)
   .WithMany(a => a.OrganizationalSubUnits)
   .HasForeignKey(a => a.ParentOrganizationalUnitId);
```

Comment: your use of ForeignKey seems weird to me. Imho, it should be `public int? ParentId { get; set; }[ForeignKey("ParentId")]public virtual OrganizationalUnit ParentUnit { get; set; }}`. But in this case I prefer use the fluent API.

Comment: I use fluent API  `modelBuilder.Entity<OrganizationalUnit>()
           .HasRequired(r => r.ParentUnit)
           .WithMany()
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`

Comment: Int? is for Optional, not for Required.

Comment: I use int? for nullable.

Comment: can't be null if required

Comment: @tschmit007 : No, it isn't required. I edit my question, plz see it.